# Starting JIRA and Bitbucket on one machine does not work

Tags: ubuntu, jira, bitbucket

I'm running JIRA with this command:

```
admin@jira:/opt/atlassian/jira/bin$ sudo ./startup.sh
```

and it works. Running on port 8080.

I'm running Bitbucket Server with this command and it works running on port 7990:

```
admin@jira:/opt/atlassian/bitbucket/bin$ sudo ./startup.sh
```

The problem is when I start JIRA, the Bitbucket server stops working, when I run Bitbucket server again, JIRA stops working.

What could be the reason why bitbucket-server kills JIRA and vice versa when both run on different ports?

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: In `conf/server.xml` for each application, what is the value of `<Server port="xxxx" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">`? Are they accidentally sharing the same port?

Comment: There's no server.xml in the bitbucket `conf` folder

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to an older version of Bitbucket server. I believe it's now `shared/server.xml` from the Bitbucket home directory.

Comment: @ScottDudley there's no `shared/server.xml` either

Comment: The `shared/server.xml` should be under the Bitbucket *home* (data) directory. which is different from the server install directory you're looking at above. I don't have the most recent version of Bitbucket running so I can't test this myself, but it's according to [Atlassian's instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BitbucketServer/Changing+the+port+that+Bitbucket+Server+listens+on).

Comment: I have been trying to get the same thing working, it appears to be an issue with running two instances of tomcat on a single server. REF: http://www.mycodingpains.com/how-to-install-multiple-instances-of-tomcat-on-a-single-ubuntu-server/